# Best approach for this data pipeline?

Tags: hive, hdfs, apache-nifi

I need to design a pipeline using Nifi, but I have some questions as I am thinking between two approaches and I am unsure which processors to use, so maybe you can help me.

The scenario is the following: I need to ingest some .csv files into my HDFS, those do not contain a date I want to use to partition the Hive tables I will later use, so I thought of two options:

1. At some point during the .csv treatment, create some kind of code snippet that is launched from Nifi to modify the .csv file adding the column with the date.
2. Create a temporary (internal?) table on hive, alter the table adding the column and finally add it to the table where I partition by date.

I am unsure which option is better (memory-wise, simplicity, resource management) or maybe if its even possible, or even if there is a better way to do it. Also I am unsure of which are the Nifi processors to use.

So any help is appreciated guys, thanks.

Comment: What about just adding the date into a file name

Comment: @dagget Yes, I can access the date w/o issue, is how to integrate it in the data flow. Modifying the CSV file and add it? Add it in a hive temp table before  the final table?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do #1 easily in NiFi without writing any code :)

The steps would be something like this:

1. Source processor to get your CSV from somewhere, probably GetFile
2. UpdateAttribute to add an attribute for the current date
3. UpdateRecord with a CsvReader and CsvWriter, adds a new date field
   with the value from #2

I've created an example of how to do this and posted the template here:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bbende/113f8fa44250c09a5282d04ee600cd09/raw/c6fe8b1b9f31bb106f9c816e4fd5ea90ebe19f80/CsvAddDate.xml

Save that xml file and use the palette on the left of NiFi canvas to upload it as a template. Then instantiate the template from the top toolbar by dragging on the template icon.

Comment: Thanks!I will test it tomorrow but looks promising!

Comment: Perfect! But the second phase is redundant since you can use expression language with `UpdateRecord`. Without this phase your suggestion would be more effecient

Comment: Yes I was thinking that to ensure that all records get the same value it would be best to set it once before hand, rather than evaluate the expression language. This may not matter if you are only calculating to the day or hour, but if you were doing a timestamp in millis you might get a different timestamp on each record.